# Java игнорирует переменную среды Path в Windows XP

Tags: java

Решил переустановить jdk в другую директорию. Переписал переменные среды, но при проверке работоспособности java (java -version) пытается запуститься из старого каталога и выдает ошибку.
Подскажите может где то нужно что-то подчистить?
Изначально jdk стоял в папке

> D:\Стас\П\Java\Библиотеки\jdk 7.79

Переставил в папку

> D:\Стас\Java\Библиотеки\jdk 7.79

Переменные среды:

`JAVA_HOME = D:\Стас\Java\Библиотеки\jdk 7.79`

`Path = %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Kaspersky Lab\Kaspersky Endpoint Security 10 for Windows\;%JAVA_HOME%\bin`

При запуске `java -version` выдает вот такое:

> Error: could not open `D:\╤Єрё\╧\Java\┴шсышюЄхъш\jre 7\lib\i386\jvm.cfg

Comment: Перегрузиться пробовали?

Comment: Да, конечно. Результат тот же.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку. Возможно и ошибка, хотя я копирую из проводника адрес.
Меня смущает то, что даже полностью очистив переменные окружения от ссылок на java все равно ссылается в несуществующую директорию как будто находит ее путь в каком то конфигурирующем файле.

Comment: JAVA_HOME поменяли?

Comment: Вот здесь: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14576802/1646082 написано странное решение, но вроде помогает. Проверьте, что у вас нет `java.exe` в папочке `Windows` и `Windows\system32`

Answer (score 1):

Огромное спасибо Vartlok.
В папке C:\WINDOWS\system32 действительно был java.exe
Как только удалил его то сразу (даже без перезагрузки) все заработало.